# How to XOR the colors under a shape? (SDL2)

Tags: sdl, sdl-2

I have an artsy side-project that is running slower than I want it to.  Basically, I want to draw a bunch of shapes and colors such that they XOR the shapes and colors that I've already drawn.  The program makes things like this:[image]

Which is seven black circles XORed onto the screen.

My method is quite slow, for each pixel, I'm looping through each circle to determine if it should be XORed.

I can draw circles with SDL_gfx, but I can't seem to find a drawing mode that XORs.  My current thought process is to use a blending mode that will at least tell me if a specific pixel is odd or even.  However, creating an SDL_Texture that can be rendered to ( SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_TARGET ) makes it unable to be directly manipulated ( SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING ).

The simple question is, how do I apply a black circle such that it XORs the pixels below it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to do this with SDL_Renderer and still have reasonable performance.  You would have to do the work in an SDL_Surface and upload it again.

I wrote SDL_gpu to enable modern graphical effects with a similar style to SDL's built-in render API.  This particular effect is trivial in GLSL if you've used it much.  If you want to avoid custom shaders, this effect is probably possible with the expanded blend mode options that SDL_gpu has.

Comment: Thanks.  I did find a picture using glsl that does make this look simple, I'll just have to polish my skills a bit.  Will look into SDL_gpu.